# Find out where MySQL is installed on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos

How do I find out where MySQL is installed on Mac OS X 10.7.9? I have MAMP installed so I presume that it is bundled with this install?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

To check MySQL version of MAMP , use the following command in Terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --version
```

Assume you have started MAMP .

Example output:

```
./mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.44, for apple-darwin8.11.1 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**UPDATE:** Moreover, if you want to find where does mysql installed in system, use the following command:

```
type -a mysql
```

`type -a` is an equivalent of tclsh built-in command `where` in OS X bash shell. If MySQL is found, it will show :

```
mysql is /usr/bin/mysql
```

If not found, it will show:

```
-bash: type: mysql: not found
```

By default , MySQL is not installed in Mac OS X.

**Sidenote:** For XAMPP, the command should be:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql --version
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor by installing MAMP, I have mysql in the location you mentioned and the command to show the version works. But, the `type` command doesn't find it. Is that normal?

Comment: MAMP does not install mysql in the search paths of `type`, therefore mysql cannot be found. You may want `find / -iname "mysql"`

Comment: please edit the title of your question to specify that you are usingMAMP

Comment: +1 for `type -a mysql`. That's so handy. I installed MySQL like 4 different time (default setup, mamp, homebrew, manually..) before I got it to work

Comment: Try : [  find / -iname "mysql" -print -quit ]  to stop right after finding the first match

Answer (score 84):

It will be found in **`/usr/local/mysql`** if you use the mysql binaries or dmg to install it on your system instead of using MAMP

Comment: Hello, I have used the dmg but I have 2 folders under local: mysql    mysql-5.5.38-osx10.6-x86_64 Why might this be?

Comment: @KorayTugay One could be a symlink to the other so that running mysql will run the full name version, that was the case on my system

Answer (score 30):

If you run `SHOW VARIABLES` from a *mysql console* you can look for **basedir**.

When I run the following:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'basedir';
```

on my system I get `/usr/local/mysql` as the Value returned.
(I am not using MAMP - I installed MySQL with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).

`mysqld`on my machine is in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` so the basedir is where most everything will be installed to.

Also util:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'datadir';
```

To find where the DBs are stored.

For more:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html

and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_basedir

Comment: This is the only answer valid for all situations

Comment: Yes, I have installed XAMPP and MySql is also gets installed with XAMPP, so when I run above query in phpMyAdmin's SQL query box I got '/opt/lampp'. Which is referring to Xampp's location.

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 20):

If you downloaded mySQL using a DMG (easiest way to download found here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) in Terminal try: `cd /usr/local/`

When you type `ls` you should see mysql-YOUR-VERSION. You will also see mysql which is the installation directory.

Source: http://geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/how_to_download_and_install_mysql_on_mac_os_x.php

Answer (score 5):

If you've installed with the dmg, you can also go to the Mac "System Preferences" menu, click on "MySql" and then on the configuration tab to see the location of all MySql directories.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/osx-installation-prefpane.html

Answer (score 5):

for me it was installed in **/usr/local/opt**

The command I used for installation is **brew install mysql@5.6**

Answer (score 3):

Or use good old "find". For example in order to look for old mysql v5.7:

```
cd /
find . type -d -name "mysql@5.7"
```

Comment: This takes forever ...

Answer (score 1):

For me I was able to get the location at the path "/opt/homebrew/etc"

I have installed mysql using homebrew.

If you are not able to get the exact path start the mysql server -> mysql.server start

then run mysql -v to check the version, it will bring you in to the mysql.
run SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'basedir'.
Navigate to path "/opt/homebrew/etc"