# how can I run mysql if I installed it from MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, command-line-interface, mamp

So I looked at this question [Find out where MySQL is installed on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144450/find-out-where-mysql-is-installed-on-mac-os-x)

I have MAMP installed and when I run: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --version` It gives me correct output for mysql version.

But if I run `type -a mysql` it says that it wasn't found, as if I don't have mysql installed.

If I want to run mysql from the terminal I can start my MAMP server,  then go to MAMP's library and run `./mysql` which will start a mysql session.

HOWEVER: I do NOT want to run it using the current MAMP's server I have. i.e Is there a way to run mysql from any directory, like without using MAMP at all?

Answer (score 0):

you should run the daemon manually but you need to setup the data before that by doing something like [data directory initialization mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded mysql from mysql site http://www.mysql.com and I can run either the one on my MAMP'S server or the one locally on my machine. I just need to decide which of the two since both are running locally.